# Trouble installing first Greasemonkey script on TBB (Firefox Tor Browser)

Tags: firefox, script, tor, greasemonkey

I installed the Greasemonkey addon, v. 4.1, which is that last version that works with Firefox 52, which is where the latest TBB is at. (TBB is a special version of Firefox.)

Clicking on "New user script..." after clicking on the Greasemonkey icon has no effect.

Clicking on "Install" on a user script page at moz-extension://... briefly takes me to another page, with code ending in .js, and then quickly takes me back to the install page. (This repeats if I try to install again.)

Clicking on the Greasemonkey icon, I do not see any item listed to manage installed scripts, and I see images elsewhere that this option should be there. This indicates no scripts are installed.

Searching for help, I found this, which says how to manually install Greasemonkey scripts in TBB: http://clraik.com/forum/showthread.php?10231-Installing-scripts-in-Tor-Browser

It says to add this directory under profile if it isn't there: Tor Browser>FirefoxPortable>Data>profile>g m_scripts

My directory structure for TBB is very different, and there is no "profile" directory anywhere within the Torbrowser directory structure. There also isn't a "FirefoxPortable" directory anywhere.

I am therefor unable to proceed with the first step, or any subsequent steps. There are a lot of places within the structure where I could add a "profile" directory, if that would even be right.

I can find no other websites that address using Greasemonky with TBB, except for two search result that give privacy warnings.

Comment: GM 4 is a major, fubar, break from earlier GM versions.  And even [GM's developers recommend that you switch to Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html). ... But if you insist on suffering through GM, you should install version 3.12, which is the latest *working* version that runs on FF52.

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try.  If it still doesn't work, I will see if I can find a script that does what I want that's compatible with Tampermoney or Violentmonkey.

Comment: I tried 3.11, the last version before they introduced webextension.  I tried two scripts that are supposed to detect unfriendings on facebook.  The scripts install, but they don't work.  I turned off NoScript to make sure it wasn't interfering.

Comment: I suspect the two scripts I tried, from 2012 and 2014, no longer work as facebook makes it a point to block anything that tries to help people detect when someone unfriends them.  Facebook Purity doesn't even do this anymore, while they claim to.  I'm giving up on this again for another year, and I'll just continue to keep track of friend list changes manually.